# Neo4j 2.1.2: Unable to delete nodes using Cypher query that worked with Neo4j 2.0.1

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I recently upgraded to Neo4j 2.1.2 from Neo4j 2.0.1 and started receiving a new error when attempting to delete nodes.

This code works in 2.0.1 to delete a node that is connecting two other nodes and replaces it with a bidirectional relationship.

```
MATCH (a:node {id: 1})
WITH a

MATCH (b1:node)-[:rel]->(a)<-[:rel]-(b2:node)
CREATE UNIQUE (b1)-[:rel]->(b2), (b2)-[:rel]->(b1)
WITH a

OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[r]-()
DELETE a, r
```

But produces the following error in 2.1.2:

```
{Code:"Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailure", Message:"Node 4746 has been deleted"}
```

I tried changing it to this:

```
MATCH (b1:node)-[r1:rel]->(a)<-[r2:rel]-(b2:node)
CREATE UNIQUE (b1)-[:rel]->(b2), (b2)-[:rel]->(b1)
DELETE r1, r2, a
```

But am still receiving the same error message. I also tried putting the DELETE within a different statement within the same transaction and that failed as well. I checked the Cypher for all the statements within the transaction and a, r1 and r2 are never accessed again post the delete. Removing the DELETE in this statement causes the transaction to succeed.

What's the right way to delete nodes as part of a transaction?

**UPDATE**

I can't get a solid repro of this bug but there is definitely something wrong. Everything will be working fine and then suddenly I will start getting error messages about Nodes being deleted or relationships not being found.

I've narrowed it down to the following query:

```
  MATCH (a:activity {id: { param0 } }), (i:file {id: { param1 } })
  CREATE (i)-[:HISTORY {id: i.id}]->(a)
  WITH a, i

  MATCH (i)-[r:HISTORY {id: i.id}]->(ph:activity)
  WHERE ph.id <> a.id
  CREATE (a)-[:HISTORY {id: i.id}]->(ph)
  DELETE r
```

I issue this as part of a larger transaction, but removing the `DELETE r` results in the error messages never being produced. Otherwise I randomly get:

ErrorCode: "",
Raw:       &errors.errorString{s:"Neo4j returned Unable to load RELATIONSHIP with id 2397. ( Neo.ClientError.Statement.EntityNotFound)"},

The odd part is that the transaction succeeds and is not rolled back even though it produces an error. At this point I believe that it is a timing issue and that's why I can't get a solid repro for it. Is there additional debugging that I can enable to help track down the problem when it occurs?

Comment: Do you run this in a bigger transaction? Or just as a single statement? Against embedded or server? And would you be able to share that database with us?

Comment: This is part of a bigger transaction against the transactional endpoint of a Neo4j server. I haven't tested it as a single statement since this was working fine in 2.0.1. I can share the full code of the transaction that produces the error privately with you (the db is empty when this test is executed). Where should I mail it to?

Comment: Nevermind, I can't reproduce the issue anymore (after hitting it for 2 hours this afternoon...). I deleted the database after testing and with a fresh database it doesn't hit the same problem. Guessing there was a bad index or something? I'll reply if I can get it to happen again.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Otherwise send it to michael at neo4j.org

Comment: It's definitely a timing issue. I'm still seeing it sporadically during my tests and once it starts happening, I usually have to delete the database to get it to stop.  I've updated the question, is there additional debugging I can enable that would help track this problem down?

Comment: Also reverting back to 2.0.1 solves all the problems. All my tests execute without issue and I after 30 minutes of trying, I can't trigger the timing issue either.

Comment: Could you send me your store and the code you use to cause this issue? And an description on how to trigger it? That would be awesome, thanks.